# How to display javascript variable as text using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to javascript. I'm using D3 to build some charts.  I'm wanting to display the number of mouse clicks over an SVG element.

Currently I can display the ellipse and can track the number of clicks on the ellipse.  I'm wanting to overlay the changing number of mouse clicks on the ellipse.

I have it working so that the initial variable is displayed, but haven't been able to solve how to display the variable changes (ie additional mouse clicks).  I want it so that as soon as the ellipse is clicked on, the text is updated.

My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 400)
        .attr("height", 800);    
    sampleSVG.append("svg:ellipse")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .attr("rx", 20)
        .attr("ry", 25)
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})
        .on("click", function(){clicks = clicks+1
                    })
    sampleSVG.append("svg:text")
        .text(clicks)
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y", 50)
        .attr("fill", "black"); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding to
        sampleSVG.text(clicks)
to my onclick function, but it didn't work.

Also as a more general question, should my text (var clicks) be appended to sampleSVG 
or should I create a new variable sampleText and overlay it over sampleSVG?

THanks for the help

R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying `sampleSVG.text(clicks)` sets the text content of the outer svg:svg element, deleting all the contained elements; you want to set the text content of just the svg:text element. You could select the text element on click:

```
.on("click", function() {
  clicks = clicks + 1;
  sampleSVG.select("text").text(clicks);
})
```

Alternatively, when you create the text element, you could save a reference to it:

```
var sampleText = sampleSVG.append("text")
    .text(clicks)
    .attr("x", 50)
```

Then you can access this element on click:

```
.on("click", function() {
  clicks = clicks + 1;
  sampleText.text(clicks);
})
```